# How can I create an icon and text in same div like table format

Tags: html, css, html-framework-7

I am using Framework 7. I need to create a div with this format.

[image]

I have the icon of height 80px x 80px and I can use it like this.

`<i class="icon icon-clock-large"></i>`

I have absolutely no idea of css. I tried using columns but they create a problem on small screen. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Below code

```css
.container {
                padding: 10px;
                width: 200px;
                color: #09cd68;
                background: #262223;
                display: block;
                font-family: verdana;
                height: 50px;
            }

            .left{
                float:left;  
            }

            .clr{
                clear:both;  
            }

            .loadingtext{
                width: 140px;
                margin: 4px 0px 0px 15px;
            }
            .pleasewait{
                font-size:13px;
            }
            .processing{
                text-transform:uppercase;
                font-size:20px;
            }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-3x"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="left loadingtext">
    <div class="pleasewait">Please wait<div>
      <div class="processing">PROCESSING</div>
  </div>
  <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the positioning of the text.

First, I used display flex to make .img and .text inline.

then just added a little margin for gutter.

Style text as long as it fits your wants.

```css
.container {
  background: #262223;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  width: 250px;
}

.img {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background: #09cd68;
}

.text {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.text p {
  color: #09cd68;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.text p:first-child {
  font-size: 16px;
}



.text p:last-child {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>please wait</p>
    <p>Processing</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `float: left;` to your icon or `display:inline-block` for both icon and text elements

Comment: And I both them to be exactly in the center of screen. Is it possible too?